# content not showing when bootstrap accordion is set to collapse at init

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Loaded data from mysql is not showing in collapsed bootstrap accordion.
It does show if class collapse is removed.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accKarin"> 
   <div class="accordion-group"> 
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accKarin" href="#group1Karin"> <img src="img/karin.png" style="width:120px;" alt="Karin" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Karin </b></a>
   </div>
   <div id="group1Karin" class="accordion-body collapse"> 
    <div class="accordion-inner"><?php $FP->Cms->display_block("index_karin", "wysiwyg");  ?>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get this to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Add `in` to `collapse` class like this:

```
<div id="group1Karin" class="accordion-body collapse in">
```

Comment: "in" is not a existing twitter bootstrap class. I just found out that the problem is in the combination with Colorbox. These use 2 different version of jQuery. So jQuery.noConflict(true); is neccessary to avoid conflicts. And yet, without this line of code, the accordion works OK, but my colorbox doesn't and vice versa.